Convert the Simulink model into C code while avoiding encapsulated parts that may result in unsuccessful porting
I used the Simulink function in Matlab to build a model of the power system as simple as possible, because I wanted to avoid the uncertainty factors generated by complex systems in the process of converting the model into C language code as much as possible. Firstly, ensure that there are no issues with model conversion before gradually optimizing and upgrading the model to achieve more complex functions. I hope to port the generated C code to the ZYQN platform, which means that full source code is required and there should be no other encapsulated parts that may cause incomplete porting. However, when setting code generation now, the option of Non reusable does not seem to guarantee that encapsulated parts will not be generated during the conversion process. How can I quickly and effectively check if there are any encapsulated parts in the generated code, or how can I avoid the generation of encapsulated parts?
I use simulink coder to make this transformation, but it seems like only a partial success.Because i need transmission is entirely composed of source code but i can not make sure whether it's as i think.

Can you elaborate on the encapsulation you see, and on the contents of your model, are you using plain Simulink, or additional Libraries, specific to the domain?

@MonkeyProof Solutions Yeah,I am using a regular Simulink model to create functions related to power system relay protection, involving both the primary and secondary sides.The self writing module on the secondary side uses data imported from the workspace, and I suspect that this data may have caused the generation of MAT files.Also
There are some MEX files, and I'm not sure if it's because I used some MATLAB functions that cannot be directly converted into C code.
